# Avoid showing table header without any data row before page break

Tags: java, flying-saucer, html-to-pdf

we are using Flying Saucer to generated pdfs (including large tables).
Our customers requirement is to repeat the table header on each page which is done by using:

```
table { -fs-table-paginate: paginate; }
```

After inserting this we discovered an new problem:
On some pages with a lot of information before the table only the table header is shown before the page break. On the next page the table header is repeated as defined by css.
How can I avoid that the table header is shown without any data rows?

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I am running into the same issue right now...